# QGIS 3 script new style more parameters

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing

Since QGIS 3.6 there has been introduced a new script style. I am fairly new to this scripting and I would like to ask for the code to do an fix of two layers and after this to make an intersect of the fixed layers.

```py
   from qgis.processing import alg
   from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsFeatureSink
   @alg(name="ex_new", label=alg.tr("Example script (new style)"), group="examplescripts", group_label=alg.tr("Example Scripts"))
   @alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name="INPUT", label="1. itsLayer")
   @alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name="INPUT2", label="2. itsLayer")
   @alg.input(type=alg.SINK, name="OUTPUT", label="Output layer")
   def testalg(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
       """
       Intersect two layers und make some SQL-Statements with the result
       """
       source = instance.parameterAsSource(parameters, "INPUT", context)
       (sink, dest_id) = instance.parameterAsSink(
           parameters, "OUTPUT", context,
           source.fields(), source.wkbType(), source.sourceCrs())
       total = 100.0 / source.featureCount() if source.featureCount() else 0
       features = source.getFeatures()
       for current, feature in enumerate(features):
           if feedback.isCanceled():
               break
           out_feature = QgsFeature(feature)
           sink.addFeature(out_feature, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)
           feedback.setProgress(int(current * total))
       return {"OUTPUT": dest_id}
```

Comment: You could create a model based on your parameters and then export this as a python script.

Comment: But in the scripts there are no alg decorator